# opening variable link in new window

Tags: html, wordpress, window

I have a wordpress site and one of the plugins pulls school info in to my site.  when someone clicks on a school the link is opened on the same page.  I would like the link to open in a new window.  I have tried and broke the site a number of times.

where would i add the blank target to the below snippet of code?

```
    <h4><a href="{$school["url"]}">{$school["schoolname"]}</a></h4>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<h4><a target="_blank" href="{$school["url"]}">{$school["schoolname"]}</a></h4>
```

Comment: THANKS!  now what about $description .= " (<a href=\"{$link}\">read more</a>"; ?  i tried to put the a target but that breaks it

Comment: $description .= " (<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"{$link}\">read more</a>";

Answer (score 1):

Add the target to the `a` tag:

```
<a href="..." target="_blank">...</a>
```

Also, to be picky, if you're using an XHTML doctype then the `target` attribute isn't valid and a strict solution would be to do the window opening with Javascript. If you're using an HTML doctype (and why not use the HTML5 doctype?), then it's grand.